# picasso error. image URL COMES from database but not set in picasso image

Tags: picasso

Picasso.with(context).load(Image.get(position)).into(new Target() {@Override public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from{Log.d("abhinav1", "onBitmapLoaded: "+bitmap); r.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));}@Override public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable{}@Override public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
}});

Answer (score 0):

after search i found that the data comes from the server in the string from then first you have to decrypt the string into bitmap and then set in imageview

Answer (score 0):

In your onBitmapLoaded method, you can use

```
   @Override
     public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom >from) {
         Log.d("abhinav1", "onBitmapLoaded: "+bitmap);
         r.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap));
     }
```

please pass the `Resources` in the `BitmapDrawable` constructor.